# Will grave shambler trigger when a weapon's durability is used up?

Tags: hearthstone

Will [grave shambler](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Grave_Shambler) trigger when a weapon's durability is used up, or just when it's destroyed by the opponent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The term destroy essentially refers to any method by which a minion or weapon is killed.  Running a weapon out of durability destroys it and as such will trigger Grave Shambler.

Comment: Because the OP only mentioned the enemy destroying your weapon: equipping a new weapon will also count the old weapon as being destroyed.